# Accessing optional property in typescript throws "property can't be undefined" error in function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

`let targetFontSize=sizes[props.size]` through `undefined` can't be an index. I understand the issue that since `prop.size` is optional it can be undefined. But I don't know how to solve this issue. Any help would be appreciated!

```
import * as React from "react";
interface ButtonProps {
  /** Button label size*/
  size?: "small" | "normal" | "large"
  /** The size of the button */
  children: string
};

const sizes = {
  small: "12px",
  normal: "18px",
  large: "24px"
};

/**
 * A Button element
 */
export const Button: React.SFC<ButtonProps> = (props: ButtonProps) => {
  let targetFontSize = sizes[props.size];
  const styles = {
    fontSize: props.size
  };
  return <button style={styles}>{props.children}</button>;
};

Button.defaultProps = {
  size: "normal"
};
export default Button;
```

Comment: How about a default value or a fallback for when it is undefined?

Comment: why are you exporting `Button` as a named export and a default? The default prop should ensure that size is never undefined. Try removing the named export and just using the default export maybe

Comment: @Chris, Sure I can try that. But it makes the purpose of `defaultProps` useless!

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak, Actually I am using styleguidist and react-docgen-typescript. It doesn't work with default exports at the moment. Hence I had export it like this

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak, anyway removing the export isn't gonna help.

Comment: you still probably shouldn't be exporting it twice but anyway, I think maybe you can see your problem here https://github.com/styleguidist/react-docgen-typescript/commit/fd7f4d36651724aed5d58d51a4958d8aabbb04d9

Comment: you should be defining your default prop in your Component

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak I had looked at the linked issue. I have already commented the same in issue. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak, Please have a look at last part. I have defined defaultProps on the Button. Btw this is a stateless component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add hashbang after prop.size

```
let targetFontSize = sizes[props.size!];
```